# How to filter a string in a column of Pandas data frame using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I use 'for' loop (e.g. '*for i in range(1996,2000,1)*') in string filtering of Pandas data frame ?

I have a data frame like this:

```
Date            Value
07/09/1997      505
05/03/1998      1005
03/02/2000      747
01/05/1998      448
06/08/1996      57
09/11/2000      673
```

I like to filter '1998' from the 'Date' column using a '*for i in range(1996,2000,1)*' loop and create a new DF so that it would look like this:

```
Date            Value
05/03/1998      1005
01/05/1998      448
```

Comment: you should always avoid for loops when working with dataframes. Use vectorized attributes like `pd.Series.dt` to access the dates and index with those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`for` loops are slower, should be ideally avoided if possible**.

Convert `Date` column to `datetime` using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then extract only `year` using [`Series.dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
In [2441]: df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
In [2446]: df = df[df.Date.dt.year.eq(1998)]

In [2447]: df
Out[2447]: 
        Date  Value
1 1998-05-03   1005
3 1998-01-05    448
```

**Additionally, per @CainãMaxCouto-Silva's comment:**

You can filter a range of years as well:

```
In [2451]: df[df.Date.dt.year.isin(range(1996,2000))]
Out[2451]: 
        Date  Value
0 1997-07-09    505
1 1998-05-03   1005
3 1998-01-05    448
4 1996-06-08     57
```

Comment: Cool! Additionally, if the user wants to use a range, not a specific year, he can use `df.Date.dt.year.isin(range(1996,2000))` with the same code structure here.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva Have added your comment in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mayank and CainãMaxCouto-Silva. My problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df[df.Date.dt.isocalendar().year.eq(1998)]



        Date  Value
1 1998-05-03   1005
3 1998-01-05    448
```